# Same result as expected but with a different format on hackerrank website using Octave

Tags: octave

I'm submitting [this hackerrank practice problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/quicksort1/problem).

Here is my code:

```
n = scanf('%d',1);
a = scanf('%d',[1,n]);
pivot = a(1);
equal = pivot; left = []; right = []; b = [];
for i = 1:length(a)-1
    if a(i+1)<equal
        left = [left,a(i+1)];
    elseif a(i+1)>equal
        right = [right,a(i+1)];
    end;
end;
b = [left,equal,right];
disp(b);
```

but it still says my answer is wrong:

```
Your Output (stdout)
   3   2   4   5   7 

Expected Output
3 2 4 5 7
```

Note the difference in spacing between the numbers.

How can I produce the expected output?

Comment: hi Luengo, thanks for your reply, can you explain a bit more? because when I changed the code into:  a = input(stdin), b = sort(a), fprintf(b)  or disp(b), it still results in the same error.

Comment: thanks, I have referred this link and nearly solved my problem on the hackerrank website, but there is still one more error I don't know how to fix: # Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT
n = scanf('%d',1);
a = scanf("%d",[1,n]);
pivot = a(1);
equal = pivot; left = []; right = []; b = [];
for i = 1:length(a)-1
    if a(i+1)<equal
        left = [left,a(i+1)];
    elseif a(i+1)>equal
        right = [right,a(i+1)];
    end;
end;

b = [left,equal,right];

disp(b);
Your Output (stdout)
   3   2   4   5   7 while Expected Output
Download
3 2 4 5 7

Comment: hi, I have edited the question, can you read that? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the formatting requirements on this site seems very strict, you will have to carefully reproduce the formatting given in the example, with one space in between each pair of numbers.

In Octave, use `fprintf` to control the formatting of the input:

```
fprintf('%f ', b)
```

will do this, but also write a space at the end. Maybe this is OK, give it a try. If it’s not, you need to output the last one separately:

```
fprintf('%f ', b(1:end-1))
fprintf('%f', b(end)) % last number without a space at the end
```

Comment: Hi Cris, thanks for reply, fprintf works and the format is correct!